# Avoiding focus-gain of first view (EditText) on Tab-Change

Tags: android, tabs, focus, android-edittext

i'm creating an application on which it is essential that none of the EditText-Views gets a focus. This should only happen, when the user points directly into one of them.
I managed to prevent the focus-gain onCreate() and onResume() via a Dummy EditText-Item.
But in my application i'm using tabs combined with scrollviews.
When the user changes to another tab for the first time, there seems to be no focus-gain (perfect!) but as soon as one switsches back to another tab my EditText-View gains focus...

I tried using die onXY events of the tabHost but didn't really get it right...
I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance,
fbtb
This code only works on the first Tabchange... how can that be? The Toast is allways shown correctly but the focus is only set on the first Tabchange... i don't get it at all :(

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onTabChanged(String bezeichner) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"This is the Tab: " + tabHost.getCurrentTab() +" der String: "+bezeichner, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0)
                    goBtn.requestFocus();

                if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 1)
                    label_maxvolume.requestFocus();
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to remove focus from any Edittext

```
final EditText eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
         InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(eText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This will basically hide the keyboard whenever you want or wherever you want it hidden.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's one part of my problem. The problem is, that the EditText loses it's content when beeing focused and i only want this to happen, when the user touches the field, not when he changes tabs.

Comment: Sometimes talking helps ;)

I changed the Events my EditText listens to from "onFocusChanged" to "onTouch"
and everthing works fine, alltough i think the way i tried it at first should work, too...

Comment: ok it didn't really help, as now the EditText doesn't gain focus when i touch it, nor the keyboard open, but i think i can fix this ;)